# Is there a max skill level?

Tags: stardew-valley

The achievements are all based on achieving level 10 in your skills. Is this the max level for a skill? And if so, when you reach this level can you continue to gain proficiency in equipment separately or are they directly tied to each other in a preset fashion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The max level you can obtain permanently is 10, but food buffs can push you higher. You can see your effective skill level on the skills screen.
[image]

That said, you do NOT appear to gain efficiency from levels above 10. Casting an Iridium rod costs 7 stamina anywhere between 10 and 13.

At the very least, fishing above 10 makes fish easier to catch. When I was trying to catch Legend, I spent two full in game days (I quit, rather than slept, so it was actually the same day, twice) trying to catch him without ever getting him above 75%, and only above 50% once. The third cycle, I ate a dish of the sea (+3 fishing) and caught him nearly effortlessly the first try. I quit again, tried to catch him without the food buff, failed hard, ate the food, caught him easily. Either there's a placebo effect or food buffs work above 10.

Comment: I believe when you eat food to boost it, it displays the change on your skills screen.  I'm fairly certain I saw a 12 or 13 on my skill screen.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the max skill level across all skills (currently) is 10. Once you reach level 10 in a skill you can still level other skills as normal. However, you can not surpass level 10.

Source: http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Skills